# Literal String Union Autocomplete for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

My problem is identical to the one in

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729

but I cannot figure out a solution in vscode using Python and intellisense.

I am not getting type hints for a union of literals with string in the call of test_function. I would like "name1" and "name2" to appear in the autocomplete.

```
from typing import Literal, Union, Optional


Name = Union[
                    Literal[
                                "name1",
                                "name2"
                           ], 
                    str]

def test_function(name: Name):
    pass

test_function("")
```

There is a work-around posted, and while I'm not familiar with the typescript syntax used, from what I can surmise, Python has no equivalent to the & operator.

Is the Name type equivalent to the string type? Is there any workaround? I want to allow arbitrary names, but also have autocomplete for hard-coded names available.

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66210054/2825570)

Comment: Then vscode reports a problem if you pass anything other than what's in the Literal.

Comment: the Typescript CompletionItemProvider has NOTHING to do with the Python CompletionItemProvider, they only live together in the shell called VSC that displays the results of the CompletionItemProviders

Comment: In this case, both CompletionItemProviders use the same logic, but the workaround for the Typescript one does not exist in the Python one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works, although I am not sure why. If you use `AnyStr` instead of `str` in the Union, then Intellisense will autocomplete your literals and VScode will not report a problem..

```
from typing import Literal, Union, AnyStr


Name = Union[
            Literal[
                        "name1",
                        "name2"
                    ], 
             AnyStr
            ]


def test_function(name: Name):
    print(name)
    pass

test_function("")
```